# Having a sidebar (like Facebook) on all VC after the signup/signin

Tags: ios, swift, sidebar

I was following this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/ and got it to work once but then lost it. I made it work for just the `MessagesTVC`, TVC for TableViewController, but now it doesn't work at all. Instead now it shows a random page table view page and its built in '< Back' button but instead of back it says '< true'. I don't know if I changed the segues or the code. This is how I current have it:
[image: Setup of the current view controllers]

So I basically want to have the side bar menu after the log in or sign up and every page after that. The code for the `MessagesTVC` is:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts

class MessagesTVC: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBAction func composeMessage(sender: AnyObject) {

    //SIGN OUT ACTION FOR NOW...
    PFUser.logOutInBackgroundWithBlock { (error: NSError?) -> Void in
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.hidden = false

}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 0
}
}
```

This is the only code I have that has anything to do with the sidebar menu besides the .h and .m files in the Supporting Files group. Basically trying to achieve the Facebook feel.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

1. All of your segues are custom and you set your segue class to SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController class.
2. You define Menu button in storyboard or from code for all the VCs in which you are using this menu.
3. In your VC viewdidload  you add this code

   ```
   SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
   if ( revealViewController )
   {
       [self.sidebarButton setTarget: self.revealViewController];
       [self.sidebarButton setAction: @selector( revealToggle: )];
       [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
   ```

   enter code here
       }

Comment: What would that code be in swift? I have no background in Objective-C.

Comment: Swift code you already have in place you check your menu button and its outlet and also segue class.

Comment: What gives you more error as I said you already have code in place i viewdidload you don't need to change that

Comment: Oh, okay so how do I fix it? because when I sipe right i get the login view instead of the menu

Comment: Did you check your segue class and also sw_front and sw_rear are setup alright as its seems problem is in storyboard segue configuration not code.

Comment: Yeah everything is as is. I even made a new project just to test it out. It doesn't work only give out a black screen with the nav bar on top

Comment: It gives me an error: 2015-09-30 23:03:21.592 mssngr[44600:4103638] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <mssngr.MainScreenVC: 0x7ff7a9c61f70>.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured it out the hard way by breaking it apart and putting it together again. Basically I didn't need to have any segue from the sidebar menu to anything but the main view controller. I linked the sidebar menu to only the navigation controller of the main screen and hooked up the rest as it should. Then I added this code without the if statement:

```
    menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
    menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer())
```

in the `viewDidLoad()` method and it worked like a charm.

[image: New Storyboard Layout]